# Boot-repair in an endless loop

Tags: boot-repair

I've tried numerous times to use the Boot-repair USB stick that was successfully updated in May of '23.

Each time, it goes into an endless loop of asking to connect to a network even though it already is. I used the built-in web browser several times and it works.

Eventually, I just go to repair, after 12 odd loops and even though it says it worked, it never has. I tried an old boot-repair from 2014 and that didn't loop. It just went straight to repair... which didn't work.

### Any clue? I don't have a screenshot.

Sorry for the delay in providing the full paste bin link...

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bMVkmsXd6T/

Note that the drive was fully functional but something happened after a normal reboot; I'd been checking Cinnamon and Gnome desktops to see if the Wifi was working on them because it wasn't in Mate. No power outage or anything, just a normal reboot led to an error page. Tried Boot-repair, and it changed to 'Missing OS'. I don't recall what the first error page said. Took 3 full days to get back up and running using a different HDD and installing 23.04 on it. I can read all my files on the old drive when used as a slave.

I'd sure be interested to know what happened to Boot-repair...it's worked for me several times in the past. First I used a USB stick from May '23...that didn't work. Then used a Boot-repair DVD from ~2014, didn't work. Then I updated the USB stick with the latest download, still didn't work.

I would love to recover this disk to save myself hours of work so any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the ppa with your Ubuntu live  installer that is same as current installed version. The ppa is more frequently updated over the ISO. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: I downloaded and installed the 'latest' ISO and same problem. It loops. Seems like a bug. And the repair routine fixed none of the drives I have (3) though boot-repair indicated it had fixed them. I don't know where BootInfo summary report would be as a search on google doesn't lead me to it or instructions on how to get it now that I'm using 23.04 on a separate disk. I am going to try to repair my original HDD with boot-repair again to see if it's feeling better today.

Comment: Okay...found that paste bin thingy but have just the # 96gR2zjtR2 but the repair again didn't work.

Comment: You need to post the full link to the pastebin site it provides, so we can click on it to see your issues.